# Zip file not downloading in PHP

Tags: php, yii, download, zip

I've implemented the code to Create Zip Folder of Files (from db path) and download zipped folder in PHP. I am using Ubuntu OS.

```
public function actionDownload($id) {
            $model = $this->loadModel($id, 'Document');
            $results = array();
            $results = $this->createZip($model);

            $zip = $results[0];
            $size = filesize($zip->filename);

            if ($zip->filename) {             
                header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
                header("Content-type: application/zip");
                header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . $model->name . "\"");
                header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
                header("Content-Length: " . $size);

                ob_end_flush();
                flush();
                readfile($zip->filename);
                // To Store User Transaction Data
                //$this->saveTransaction();
                //ignore_user_abort(true);
                unlink($zip->filename);
                $zip->close();

                // Delete newly created files
                foreach ($results[1] as $fl) {
                    unlink($fl);
                }
            }       
    }


public function createZip($model) {

        $data = Document::model()->findAll('parent_folder=:id', array(':id' => (int) $model->document_id));
        $fileArr = array();
        foreach ($data as $type) {
            $fileArr[] = $type->path;
        }

        $filestozip = $fileArr; // FILES ARRAY TO ZIP
        $path = Yii::app()->basePath . DS . 'uploads' . DS . Yii::app()->user->id;

        //$model->path = trim(DS . $path . DS); // DIR NAME TO MOVE THE ZIPPED FILES        

        $zip = new ZipArchive();
        $files = $filestozip;
        $zipName = "USR_" . Yii::app()->user->id . "_" . $model->name . "_" . date("Y-m-d") . ".zip";

        $fizip = $path . DS . $zipName;
        if ($zip->open($fizip, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
            foreach ($files as $fl) {
                if (file_exists($fl)) {
                    $zip->addFile($fl, basename($fl)) or die("<p class='warning'>ERROR: Could not add file: " . $fl . "</p>");
                }
            }
        }

        $resultArr = array();
        $resultArr[] = $zip;
        $resultArr[] = $files;

        return $resultArr;
    }
```

The Zip creation code working fine and its creating zip file there but the issue is owner of the file is **www-data** and file permission is **Read-Only**.

When I am trying to set `chmod($zip->filename, 0777)` permission to that zipped folder then its showing an error?

```
Error 500
chmod(): No such file or directory
```

In fact file is present there.

If I am trying without `chmod()` then its showing me error of

```
Error 500
filesize(): stat failed for /home/demo.user/myapp/public_html/backend/uploads/1/USR_1_kj_2013-12-23.zip
```

and then its not downloading the zip file.

This is really weird issue I am facing. It seem to be some permission issue of zip file that's why `filesize()` is not able to perform any operation on that file but strange thing is `chmod()` also not working.

Need Help on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If `www-data` has read permissions, the file permissions are properly set. No `chmod` required.

You need to call `$zip->close()` **before** the download, as only on `$zip->close()` the file will be written to disk. `readfile()` will not work unless the file is written to disk.

---

A smarter way, could be to create the archive in memory only using the `php://memory` stream wrapper. However this is only an option if you need the archive for a single download only.

Comment: Folder has already read-write permission but when PHP creating zip file in that folder then it has no read-write permission

Comment: have you added `$zip->close` ? does it return `true` ?

Comment: Yes $zip->close() is returning blank page if I use it before download

Comment: yeah, I see. It must be **before** the download. In `createZip()`

Comment: Where should I write zip->close() ? can you pls guide me ?

Comment: after the loop where you `$zip->adddFile()`

Comment: creating zip but returns blank page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43745/discussion-between-ultimate-and-hek2mgl)

Comment: hi, not having much time at the moment. maybe later